# JS parse object wrapped in a string using same quotes as object keys

Tags: javascript, json, string, parsing

Consider the following event payload data returned via WS:

```
{ 
  id: "1", 
  foo: "{"bar":"baz"}"
}
```

The current output of `JSON.stringify(event.foo)`:

```
"{\"bar\":\"baz\"}"
```

Also consider the backend have no real way to return the `foo` value formatted differently and I need to find a way to parse the string associated to this `foo` key in order to access it's value of `bar`.

The identified problem is the fact that the quotes used to wrap the whole supposed object are the sames used in the object itself, resulting in making `JSON.parse()` impossible.

I'm wondering if there is a "clean" way to achieve this.

So far, I tried:

- using `JSON.parse()` which fails due to the format of the string raising `Unexpected end of JSON input`
- trimming external quotes and converting inner ones to single then parsing, results in same error.
- using `new Object(...)` based on the string (trimmed of external quotes)
- replacing all quotes with single ones and wrapping it again in double ones to parse it.

Any input appreciated

Comment: `JSON.parse(obj.foo)` ?

Comment: is `foo` value really `"{"bar":"baz"}"` ? Or `"{\"bar\":\"baz\"}"` ?

Comment: The problem is that you are not forming the values properly, you have to escape the double quoutes inside the double qoutes string declaration or either change the qoutes that

Comment: it's really "{"bar":"baz"}" unfortunately. 
JSON.parse(obj.foo) is not going ot work as this is not valid JSON.

Comment: Then, the clean way is to fix the backend.

Comment: You have to change the backend to return valid JSON. That is the only valid way to go really. Everything else will cause lots of trouble and also open your system to code insertion attacks.

Comment: I know right, but it's not going to happen so i just wantied to make sure the clean solution is impossible with the communauty.

Comment: *it's not going to happen* why ?

Comment: As we don't have control on the backend right now. Thanks for your time :)

Comment: To be absolutely sure about each individual character, could you do `console.log(JSON.stringify(payload))` and add that output to your question? As you have it now it is ambiguous as it is not clear whether you are showing a string literal without the quotes (raw), a JavaScript object with syntax errors, or still something else. Or alternatively, provide a line of JavaScript code that assigns the intended payload to some variable.

Comment: Done @trincot! I was apparently wrong as it seems like the string is using escape characters...

Comment: Where did the `id` go in that output? Anyway for that part, the very first comment above applies: use `JSON.parse`: `let foo = JSON.parse(event.foo); console.log(foo.bar);`

Comment: The event.data is in fact event.foo in my example. Your solution is not going to wok and will raise:
SyntaxError: Unexpected end of JSON input. The problem is is that this string is not valid JS at all and have to be formatted somehow.

Comment: If it returns invalid JavaScript, then you are going to have to build a parser that knows how to handle the invalid code and make it valid. There is no easy hack to make it work, and I am betting there could be endless edge cases depending on what is in the data.

Comment: It's precisely what I'm going to do, if you have any example or good practices please, feel free to share.

Comment: @gastngouron, you tell use that the output of `JSON.stringify(event.foo)` is `"{\"bar\":\"baz\"}"`. This means that `JSON.parse(event.foo)` will **not** raise an error (it is easy to test this in the console. See [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/atrh5f8y/)). Evidently you have a *different* value there. Also you demonstrate that `event` is a JS object, so the object literal at the start of our question has syntax errors. Please fix it to reproduce *exactly* the `event` object you refer to. Please provide a reproducible example.

Comment: You will not be able to use JSON.parse or anything until you get the quote situation fixed. That is what is what would be a PITA to solve. If the data is simple inside of it, then a reg exp might work, but if the data inside is complicated, it may not work.

Comment: Go to [XYProblem.org](http://xyproblem.info)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem here is the backend should really be fixed, but some reason you can not do it. Next issue is you can "fix it" on the front end, but you are putting a band aid on the problem and it will fall off when the data that comes back is not what you expect. So the solutions will be error prone unless you know the data coming back will be a specific type.

With this said, you can fix the invalid JSON that you have in your simple example with a couple of regular expressions. Problem is, if your data contains characters such as } in the text, this is going to fail.

```js
var response = `
{
  id: "1",
  foo: "{"bar":"baz"}",
  goo: "{"gar":"gaz"}"
}
`
var reObj = /"(\{[^}]*})"/
while (response.match(reObj)) {
  response = response.replace(reObj, '$1')
}
var reKey = /^\s+(\S+):/m
while (response.match(reKey)) {
  response = response.replace(reKey,'"$1":')
}
var obj = JSON.parse(response)
console.log(obj)
```

Comment: Thank you very much for providing this code alongside to the warnings on using it. Choosing your answer as it actually solves my problem and perfectly sums up the context.